# Silverlight MouseLeave not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0

Considering that piece of code :

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Border x:Name="brd1" Height="100" Width="100" Background="Blue" 
                MouseLeftButtonUp="brd1_MouseLeftButtonUp" 
                MouseLeave="brd1_MouseLeave" />

</Grid>
```

C# :

```
private void brd1_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    brd1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
}

private void brd1_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Mouse Leave");
}
```

Why is the MouseLeave not firing when setting Visibility = Collapsed (ie : when I click on the border)?

Is there a way to always catch the MouseLeave event even if the control disappears (or one of its parent)?  I cannot listen to the MouseButtonUp event, since my control can appear/disappear asynchronously at any time.

(note : my application is far more complex than that, this was just a simple example of what I need to do)

Comment: Sorry had to read the whole thing, anyway once it's visibility is toggled its gone, you could go for opacity instead maybe.

Comment: No, I must use visibility (actually its one of its parent which disappear so I cannot even listen to visibility property change)

Comment: Why can't you listen to the property change of the parent?

Comment: My control is super generic.  And is used throughout my application at different places, with many different parents, so short asnwer; No :)

Comment: Might consider just throwing a transparent rectangle or something in there as a placeholder to accept hittestvisibility when the other thing is collapsed or something

Comment: As per my knowledge, to handle Mouse Leave Event that control atleast needs to be visible then we can set event on that particular control. can't u set visibility hidden and then try and set it hittestvisibile property.

Comment: No I cannot do such things, I do not control when the objects appears or disapears.  This is done asynchronously.  There is hundreds of controls displayed at the same time (those are tags that are moving/appearing/disapearing in a map).  The same control is also used in dialogs and other controls.  So I really need something generic here.